# When is ACTION_USER_PRESENT sent except for the screen unlocking?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

[The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) says:

> Broadcast Action: Sent when the user is present after device wakes up
>   (e.g when the keyguard is gone).

Are there any cases when `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` is sent except for the screen unlocking?